# Exhaustive documentaion for tkinter filedialog.askdirectory

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, documentation

I am using tkinter `filedialogue.askdirectory()` and want to know what options I can enter in. The [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#module-tkinter.filedialog) just has `**options` with no description of what options are valid.

In general, I have found [tkdocs](https://tkdocs.com/index.html) useful but, for filedialogue they don't mention any options. Something like Java's javadocs are really useful because they're exhaustive.

Does there exist exhaustive documentation for tkinter filedialog? For tkinter in general?

Comment: They're described at the beginning where it says "The following keyword arguments are applicable to the classes and functions listed below:"

Comment: Oh I missed that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical documentation for tk (upon which tkinter is built) can be found here: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/contents.htm

The documentation for choosing a directory is here: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/chooseDirectory.htm

Comment: I suggest to use a link to the current documentation, rather than a version-specific link: https://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/contents.htm